# Performance issue with hiding header on scrolling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am trying to build a navigation bar which:

- starts off with a big height
- hides when scrolled down
- shows a shrunk version when scrolled up
- grows to full height when fully scrolled to the top

So far, I found a way that works. But there must be a more efficient way. I have a function to hide and show the navigation bar – and one Interval to grow again when I reached the top. I tried to combine them but always failed... Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </header>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
var shrinkHeader = 200;
function tellMeAStory() {
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-200px";
    $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}

setInterval(function(){
  var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
   if (scroll < 10){
    $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
  } else {}
},250)

function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    };
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 200px;
}

.grow{
  height: 200px;
}

.shrink{
  height: 50px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Jimmey/wry54an7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of improvements I would do:

- Remove jQuery since you only add or remove a class with it.
- Cache your selectors especially when they are in a loop.
- [Throttle your scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Scroll_event_throttling) since it can fire at a high rate.
- Remove your `setInterval` function which is not necessary here.

```js
var prevScrollpos = getCurrentScroll();
var shrinkHeader = 200;
var ticking = false;

// Cache it so you don't have to get it on every scroll event
var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var currentScrollPos = getCurrentScroll();

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        navbar.style.top = '0';
      } else {
        navbar.style.top = '-200px';
        navbar.classList.add('shrink');
      }

      if (currentScrollPos < 10) {
        navbar.classList.remove('shrink');
      }

      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});

function getCurrentScroll() {
  return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 200px;
}

.grow {
  height: 200px;
}

.shrink {
  height: 50px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header id="navbar" class="navbar">
  <a href="#start">Start</a>
  <a href="#one">One</a>
  <a href="#two">Two</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not hard to combine them. I would suggest doing something like:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
var shrinkHeader = 200;

window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScrollPos < 10){
    $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
  }
  else if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-200px";
    $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}

function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
};
```

You could also track the last operation and, if is the same, don't do any operations on the doom (this way it will be faster).

Also is a good practice to use classes instead of inline style. You might want to consider using classes for showing/hiding the bar. You could just have 3 classes and no inline style needed:

[Fiddle example for classes](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcg4j5a6/15/)